# How to load a folder of images in Winforms (C#) application?

Tags: winforms, image, load

I have folder of images, which I want to load into my WinForms (C#) application. Once it is loaded into my application, then when I click on any image that should become "Button" control backgroundImage. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `PictureBox`?

Comment: Yes, but i think if we have 35+ images in a folder then this mean 35+ pictureBox controls on the form ... is it worth using picturebox? Please correct me, if I am wrong...

Comment: I don't see any problem with that as long as your pictures are not 3MB each

Comment: Please provide me some code as to how to do it? For example, if i have 5 images in the folder then how to create picturebox dynamically and load all the images (C#)? Thanks in adavance.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78037-dynamically-create-multiple-picture-boxes/